# Adding Array Items to a ComboBox

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

The C# program I'm trying to run is supposed to read a file that contains a car's model, manufacturer, year and VIN number. These items are put into an array and then the VIN numbers are to be placed in a ComboBox so that the user selects a VIN and the corresponding model, manufacturer, and year are each in their own respective TextBox's below.

When I run the program I get

> error System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: item.

Here's the chunk of my code where the issue is happening.

```
 StreamReader inputFile;

        int i = 0, count=Vehicles.Length;
        if (openFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            inputFile = File.OpenText(openFile.FileName);

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                Vehicles[i].Model = inputFile.ReadLine();
                Vehicles[i].Manufacturer = inputFile.ReadLine();
                Vehicles[i].Year = inputFile.ReadLine();
                Vehicles[i].VIN = inputFile.ReadLine();
                i++;               
                for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
                {
                 vinCBox.Items.Add(Vehicles[j].VIN);
                }
             }
```

To make sure the the VIN values are actually going into the array I printed out a MessageBox showing one the VIN values at a certain index.

Comment: The error seems to occur at a point when parameter "item" is being passed to some function which doesn't accept item to be Null. I don't see such call in the code snipped you provided. Can you please clearify when the error occurs.
It seems to me like Vehicles[j].VIN is null, which means either your count is exceeding the true length of Vehicles or something is wrong with the initialization of Vehicles, such that some of the values of Vehicles[] are Null.

Comment: Can you please provide the code, where you create your array of vehicles.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: @Marcus You might be right about count. I created the array as Vehicles[100] and have count set to Vehicles.Length. Out of curiosity I printed out count's value after reading the file and it says that it is still 100 even though there aren't 100 lines in the file.

Comment: I am glad that I could help. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Set `Vehicles` as `DataSource` of your `ComboBox` and set `"VIN"` as it's `DisplayMember`.

Comment: @MartinBackasch My array declaration is: Car[] Vehicles = new Car[100]; It's coming out the structure I created, Car, where I declared model, manufacturer, year, and vin as public strings. I have the reading of the file in a while loop which reads it line by line and assigns each line  as follows: Vehicles[ i ].Model=inputFile.ReadLine(). This goes on for manufacturer, year, and vin followed by i++ where i is initialized at 0. Hope that clears some things up.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding our discussion in the comments, the error seems to be that the length of Vehicles[] doesn't match the value count and thus, the loop exceeds the true length of the vehicles list.

Update:

```
 StreamReader inputFile;

    int i = 0, count=Vehicles.Length;
    if (openFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        inputFile = File.OpenText(openFile.FileName);

        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            Vehicles[i].Model = inputFile.ReadLine();
            Vehicles[i].Manufacturer = inputFile.ReadLine();
            Vehicles[i].Year = inputFile.ReadLine();
            Vehicles[i].VIN = inputFile.ReadLine();
            i++;               

         }

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
             vinCBox.Items.Add(Vehicles[j].VIN);
        }
     }
```

Make sure your input file you are opening with the system-dialog has one entry per row. The ReadLine() method reads "away" the line it is currently processing, leaving the data stream with the rest of the lines but the one it just processed. If your data format is a comma seperated format (.csv), additional steps are required, to split each read line into the several values (Model, VIN, etc.)

Comment: So would this be then that it's adding empty values into everything from 100 down to the last line on my txt file or that my loop putting the strings into the array isn't correct?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code you are using to load data into Vehicles[]. The problem you currently have is that Vehicles.length() is 100. Even if your source file only consists of 20 vehicles, your loop will alway go from 0 to 99. You need to set count to the actual value of added vehicles. Therefore it is necessary to see, how you are adding the data from your sourcefile.

Comment: @SIB Do you have any further issues regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use an array that has a fixed length. Instead use a `List<Vehicle>` that grows automatically as you insert items.
The loop you make to insert items into the ComboBox is nested within the reading loop, i.e. you are adding all items repeatedly again and again.
The ComboBox can be populated by assigning the data source. No need to add items.

```
var Vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
if (openFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
    using (var inputFile = File.OpenText(openFile.FileName)) {
        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream) {
            var v = new Vehicle {
                Model = inputFile.ReadLine(),
                Manufacturer = inputFile.ReadLine(),
                Year = inputFile.ReadLine(),
                VIN = inputFile.ReadLine()
            };
            Vehicles.Add(v);
        }
    } // The using statement closes the file automatically here.

    // Fill the listbox;
    vinCBox.DataSource = Vehicles;
}
```

In the `Vehicle class, override ToString(). The ListBox automatically uses this string to display the items in the ListBox.
You can retrieve the selected item with:

```
var selectedVehicle = (Vehicle)vinCBox.SelectedItem;
```

So, there is no need to add strings to the combobox and then to convert them back to vehicles once an item is selected. ListBoxes and ComboBoxes can store data of any type directly.